# MinGW compiler doesn't need function declarations?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, mingw

I have these two files:

```
// first.c
int main(void) {
  putint(3);
}
```

and

```
// second.c
#include <stdio.h>
void putint(int n) {
  printf("%d",n);
  getchar();
}
```

When I run gcc 4.6.1 under Win XP:

```
gcc first.c second.c -o program.exe
```

It has no problem and writes 3 to stdout. It doesn't need `putint` declaration in *first.c*. How is this possible? Is this standard behavior?

I have tested this on MSVC 2008 Express and it runs only with the declaration as expected.

```
// first.c
void putint(int);
int main(void) {
  putint(3);
}
```

---

**Solved**, thanks for hints, these options helped to show the warning:

- -Wimplicit
- -std=c99 (MinGW 4.6 still uses [gnu90](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) by default)

Comment: look up "implicit function declaration"

Comment: I did. I am surprised there is no warning at all. I wonder why?

Comment: Because you didn't tell gcc to warn you. Look up the gcc command line usage.

Comment: Actually GCC doesn't still use C89 by default; it uses what they call "gnu99" mode, which is based on C99, but has lots of nonstandard extensions, and also still allows some legacy constructs (like implicit function declarations) that were permitted in C89 but not C99.

Comment: I'll bet that the file wasn't named `first.c` in MSVC 2008 Express, either.  The file was probably named `first.cpp` (or something ending in `.cpp)`, which will cause the file to be compiled as C++ where prototypes are required.  If the filename ends in `.c`, MSVC will compile it by default as C and will not complain about the missing declaration/prototype (unless you crank up the warning level).

Comment: @MichaelBurr: good guess :) but the point is already solved. Thank you, guys.

Comment: @R.. Unless you have a rather advanced version of gcc, the default is -std=gnu90

Comment: Hmm, it looks like they still haven't changed the default... I thought it changed somewhere in the 4.6 or 4.7 cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a legacy "feature" of C that should not be used as of several decades ago. You should use a compiler with settings that will warn you if you do something like this.  Gcc has several switches that you should specify when using it & one of them will give you a warning for this.

Edit: I haven't been using gcc myself, but switches that you should check out are -pedantic,  -Wall, -Wextra, and -std.

The compiler that is accepting this is assuming, per the old language definition, that since you didn't see fit to tell it otherwise, the function a) returns an int value and b) since you pass it an int (or if you passed it something that could be promoted to an int) the function expects that argument to be an int.

As @veer correctly points out, this should generally work in your particular case. In other cases, however, differences between the implicit assumptions for a function without a prototype and the function's actual signature would make things go boom.

Comment: Actually, the compiler implicitly defines `extern int putint();` (i.e. takes any and whatever parameters), which happens to work here :-) you don't need to explicitly know the amount of space for parameters because the `cdecl` calling convention delegates stack management to the caller.

Comment: @veer You are entirely correct. I was thinking in general and didn't look closely at this specific case. In some other related cases, things could be different. If the function actually returned a long on a big endian machine, if nothing else, the return values are likely to not be what you expected. Similarly, if the function was expecting a long (and a long was bigger than an int), it would be using some bits from something else as part of the value. Further, the function would be looking in the wrong place for any subsequent parameters.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't just for MinGW, but all standard versions of gcc. As noted, this is legal in C89; gcc defaults to 'gnu89' (not 99), which also accepts the code without warning. If you switch to c99 or gnu99 (or later, such as c11) you'll get a warning by default, but it will still compile.

Answer (score 0):

As is noted by others, this is standard behavior for C conforming compilers. Naming your files .c partially puts it in C mode. It'll have fun things like "built-in functions" (printf() etc.) and all sorts of legacy C things.

I'd like to add to what others have said that I experienced recently, though. MS expressly dropped support for C past C90, and their C90 support is poor to say the least. I'm not entirely sure standard ANSI C90 codebases would compile under newer VS's, because it is basically the C++ compiler with lots of stuff disabled (whereas GCC actually has a C compiler). They did this in order to promote C++. If you want to use real C, you can't really do it in MS Visual Studio, any edition, unless you want to be declaring all your variables at the start of functions, etc.